# TV Series - A girl living in a hotel has a ghost friend that only she can see

Tags: story-identification, tv, ghost

When I was a kid in Iran, around 1999, I remember there was a TV series where a girl and her family had bought a hotel and were living there. The girl had a fringe haircut and had become friends with a ghost that only she could see. The series was real people, but the ghost was animated, of indeterminate gender, and looked a bit like [Casper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_the_Friendly_Ghost).

Regarding plot, I remember going down the stairs, lots of stairs, and that the building was quite old as well.

Comment: This is a bit sparse on detail, although *thank you* for providing a time period when you were "a kid". We have a series of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to help elicit details. Try to edit the answers to those questions into your question to help us help you.

Comment: Where were you in 1999/what language was the show in? Do you remember how many episodes there were that you saw? Do you remember any of the specific plots?

Comment: I could guess the serie was either north american or european or australian!

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to suggest that it was *Polterguests*, which was a British comedy series that ran for one eight-episode season. In that series, there was the mother, Annie, a former ballet dancer, and her ten-year-old daughter Ella. Unfortunately, the daughter didn't have a fringe haircut; there was a boy who appeared in one episode who had a fringe haircut. The girl often went down a set of stairs into the basement where she had first met the ghosts. There were *three* ghosts (named Tristan, Kneecaps, and Squiffy), who helped with the running of the hotel, but it went badly. Unfortunately, the ghosts aren't animated either, they are chroma-keyed into many of their scenes. But this is the closest series I could find to what you described.

[IMDB for Polterguests](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196283/)

[Title card at IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196283/mediaviewer/rm602164224)

### Opening Credits

Comment: Thanks for the guess but unfortunately polterguests is not the one I have in mind